# STM32F4 Discovery Board USB CDC FS

Tags: stm32f4discovery

I try to implement USB CDC FS on the discovery Board from STM. But it is really frustrating.

I created a project via Cube MX with the HAL libraries. At the end I want a data rate near 500 kByte/s. Till now I can see my device in the device manager but really often I cannot open the com port in Hterm. Hterm is only not responding.

```
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      CDC_Transmit_FS(buf, 300);
      HAL_Delay(1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}
```

I initialise the clocks correctly. Maybe the virtual com port driver cannot buffer the high amount of data they are comeing from the MCU?!
If I increase the delay time in the while loop, sometimes I can open the com port and get the data. The highest data rate I got were about 70 kByte/s. Too less:(

Are there any known bugs in the software? I already increased the heap and stack sizes, but it didn't  fix the problem.

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the following two points,

   1) Set "wMaxPacketSize" to 64 from 2 (or any value) in USB CDC
   device Configuration Descriptor for Endpoint IN Descriptor in
   usbd_cdc.c file. The maximum endpoint size for Full speed
   usb is 64 bytes.

   2) Increase the HCLK and you should see higher data rate.

   CDC speed depends on many factors unlike HID where you have
   guaranteed data rate. CDC is the fastest if and only if bus is free
   with theoretical speed of 1.5 MB/s.  I have used STM32F7 disco board
   and managed to achieve 500+ KB/s data rate with HCLK 120MHz just a
   week ago.

   NOTE: Do check the USB clock frequency is set to 48MHz else its
   difficult to get it work.

Wish you good luck.

Regards,

Jagadeep.

Comment: Also make sure to disable VBUS sensing while creating code from cube.

Comment: Hello Jaggu, thanks for your help. The wMaxPacketSize is already set to 64 Byte and HCLK is set to 168 MHz and also the USB Clock is set correctly. Therefore it is so desperate. The strange thing is that with a little delay (HAL_Delay(5)) it is working and I can open the com port but data rate is low( less then 70 kbyte/s). When I lower the delay HTerm and other Terminals hung up. And sometimes I cannot open the com port at all never mind which delay is set. The usb port shall be free, there are no othe usb devices connectet.

Comment: Okay. Try to have delay of few seconds. Lets say 10 seconds before you start pumping data from device to host. Make sure the terminal is ready to receive the data well before the end of delay. The concept is there must be a terminal software ready to receive when device starting sending data.